# Hiding headers from a query in java program

Tags: java, printwriter, properties-file

So i have a program that spits out data from google to a csv file. What i want to do is allow users to choose to display the headers or not via using a string.

Here is my printer:

```
...some code
    // getting the queries to print
    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
        pw.println("No results Found.");
        System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

    // Print column headers.

      for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
          pw.print(header.getName() + ", ");
      }
      pw.println();

     // Print actual data.
     for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
       for (String column : row) {
         pw.print(column + ",");
       }
       pw.println();
     } 
     pw.close();
   }
 }
}
```

I have a properties file that is connected to my program and i want to put it so that when a user types in no in the header part of the properties file i dont want the headers to show.

I was thinking about converting the header part into a string and putting it in the if then statement. any suggestions? thx in advanced

EDIT:

```
// column headers statement
     if (headers=="yes") {
         for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) 
             pw.print(header.getName() + ", ");
    } else {
    // Print column headers.
    for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
        pw.print("" + ", ");
    }
    pw.println();
  }

 // getting the queries to print
    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
        pw.println("No results Found.");
        System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

     // Print actual data.
     for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
       for (String column : row) {
         pw.print(column + ",");
       }
       pw.println();
     } 
     pw.close();
   }

 }   
}
```

But what I have now is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is first, you are not checking the user input correctly to match

You need to change

```
if (headers=="yes") {
```

to

```
if (headers.equals("yes")) {
```

I would also get rid of the else statement for printing out nothing in the first row except commas. Do you really want the first row to just be commas?

Make sure to close your stream at the end no matter what, too. It looks like your pw.close() is in an else statement.